# URLSessionTask failed with error: A server with the specified host could not be found

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, networking, alamofire

I have an iOS app that uses Alamofire to make network requests. Some of my users are reporting that they are unable to use the app and receive the following error message (when sending request to our server): "URLSessionTask failed with error: A server with the specified host could not be found."

I have tested my app under various network conditions, including bad connection, no connection, and cellular data, and everything works fine. However, I have not been able to reproduce this issue on my own no matter what I do.

What could be causing this error for some users? Is there anything I can do to prevent this issue from occurring?

Here's the code

```
static func postUserToAPI(params: Parameters, headers: Alamofire.HTTPHeaders, completion: @escaping (Error?) -> ()) {
        AF.request(URL.EndPoints.userURL, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers)
            .validate()
            .response { response in               
                if response.error == nil {
                    completion(nil)
                }
        
                else {
                    completion(response.error)
                }                
            }
 }
```

The user that reported this issue is using iPhone 14 and iOS 16.

Comment: Maybe that's something wrong with your `URL.EndPoints.userURL`, are you sure it is,  always, a valid URL?

Comment: yes, it works on my device.

Comment: Could the user use some VPNs, or other blocking having issues with DNS or something like that?

Comment: @Larme the user does not have any issues with other apps like whatsapp etc. and btw we're using our own server, so, could it be a backend or endpoint issue?

Comment: @Larme just tested with VPN, it works fine. What can be the blocking issues with DNS?

Comment: Ask them if they use content or ad blockers.

Comment: @Paulw11 what do you mean?

Comment: I have experienced cases where users have installed content blockers and privacy filters such as cloud flare 1.1.1.1 that prevents apps from working correctly

Comment: @Paulw11 If that's the case, what can I do to fix then?

Comment: It's their issue. Some "networks" (content blockers, private company networks etc) blocks going too some web sites, so it could be the case here, with blocking some DNS or something like that. It's hard to tell what's blocking them exactly.

Comment: Exactly, if this is the problem, then they need to resolve it by either turning off the blocker or possibly white listing your site.